# Push array in checkboxes array, but I am facing some problem in Angular 2

Tags: angular

Here I am getting list of checkboxes from a component

```
<div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let m of modelupdatecurrencycheckbox">
    <input class="form-check-input"
        (change)="updatecurrencyselect(m.name)"
        [(ngModel)]="m.checked" name="{{ modelupdatecurrencycheckbox.name }}"
        type="checkbox" id="{{m.name}}"
        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">

    <label class="form-check-label" for="{{m.name}}">
        {{m.name}}
    </label>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect" (click)="onSubmitupdatecurrencyCheckbox()">SAVE</button>
</div>

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="added">
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addedinput()">add</button>
```

The array is pushing, but the array is not posting:

```
added:any=""
updatecurrencycheckbox:any={ tablename:"updatecurrency" };
modelupdatecurrencycheckbox = [
    {
        name: 'INR  ',
        checked: false,
    },{
        name: 'USD  ',
        checked: false
    },{
        name: 'Euro  ',
        checked: false,
    },{
        datasas:[]
    }];

addedinput(){

    this.datasas = this.modelupdatecurrencycheckbox
            .push(
                {
                    name: this.added,
                    checked: false
                });
              console.log("sda" + JSON.stringify(datasas))
}

onSubmitupdatecurrencyCheckbox(){
    var data = {
        array:this.modelordercurrencycheckbox,
        tablename:"updatecurrency"
    }

    this.dataService.postcustomertablepreferences(data).subscribe(
        (response) => console.log(response),
        (error) => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

Service to post the data in MongoDB using an API URL:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import {Http, URLSearchParams, RequestOptions, Response, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import {HttpHeaders, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class adminservice{

    constructor (public _http:Http, public http:HttpClient){}

    private url2="/api/users/savepreferences";
    private url3="/api/users/fetchpreferences";

    postcustomertablepreferences(modelcheckbox){
        return this._http.post(this.url2, modelcheckbox, {withCredentials:true}).map(res=>res.json());
    }

    getpreferences(data){
        return this._http.post(this.url3, data, {withCredentials:true}).map(res=>res.json());
    }
}
```

I am facing a problem to push the array in modelupdatecurrency and then trying to post it.

Comment: can you add same on plunker?

Comment: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/325FekZYIBtxESYz?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1    @KapilThakkar

Comment: Plnkr does't work.. can you please update same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.datasas = this.modelupdatecurrencycheckbox.push()
```

The `push()` method returns a new length of array.

Please refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

`console.log("sda" + JSON.stringify(datasas))` - instead of this, use:

```
 console.log("sda" + JSON.stringify(this.modelupdatecurrencycheckbox))
```

Comment: thanks it is showing properly as I want but will you please tell me why it is not send the push items in node console @kapilthakur

Comment: Sir when i console it is showing but in backend of mongodb it showing predefined checkbox not show added checkbox

Comment: sorry dost, did't get your problem..if possible thn show me in plnkr. thanks.